# search in a subgraph of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want do the following, I want to run an index search and collect all the nodes, path etc, store the new subgraph and run another search on that new subgraph.

For example:

- First Search
  `CALL apoc.index.search("cat", "Category.name:fashion") YIELD node AS catg`
- Second search 
  `CALL apoc.index.search("cat", "Category.name:dresses") on the new resultant graph`

The data is very similar to Amazon's Taxonomy tree, where the top is *fashion* and then it has tree below it. So there are multiple Root nodes.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer depends on how your data looks like and what you want to achieve. The manual indexes are for full text queries on a defined set of nodes, I think you can't really chain them.

Comment: @MartinPreusse if we can't chain the full text query, can we build the sub-graph and use Match on that.

Comment: As part of index search can we also match on the node properties, for example search on name and match property gender ?

Comment: So are you modeling categories as properties on nodes? Is there a reason why you can't model categories as nodes themselves, and create relationships between those and products (or whatever it is the category applies to)? That would simplify your queries, as you would be looking for any nodes which have relationships to your two :Category nodes for "fashion" and "dress"

Comment: @InverseFalcon each category is a node and there is a relation between each category called belongs. That means I can run a query which says match all nodes which match dresses and belongs to fashion*. Let me try that, thanks.

Comment: Hope that works for you. I'll extract that suggestion to an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend altering your data model. Rather than having categories as properties or list items in properties, they could be modeled as :Category nodes. That way a product's categories are defined by the relationships they have to :Category nodes, which also allows easier queries based on category: match on the desired categories, then match on products that have relationships with those categories.